# How does UNIX handle a move of a file between two disk file systems?

Tags: unix, disk

I have three directories on a UNIX box, as described below:

```
/tmp mapped on /dev/mapper/data-tmpVol1
/var mapped on /dev/mapper/data-varVol1
/opt mapped on /dev/mapper/data-optVol1
```

1. If I perform a move operation from /tmp to /var, will the UNIX do in fact a copy since there are two different file systems behind scene?
2. If I want an instant move, is it better to copy the file first in a /var/staging and perform a move from /var/staging to /var/input?

Context around the issue: I have a process which scans for files in /var/input, and I've seen cases when it picked up half-copied files (when moving directly from /tmp to /var/input).

Regards,

Cristi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When moving across file systems, you may like to create a file in the destination directory with a temporary filename, e.g. `my-file.txt~`. The scanning process must ignore such temporary filenames. When the file is complete you `rename` it to the final name. This way when the file (with a final name) exists it is complete, or it doesn't exist at all.

Comment: Thanks. A good solution that was taken into consideration. The only issue is that I don't really have control over the target process to make it ignore files. It is configured to pick up everything.

Comment: @Cristi Then create a temporary file in the target filesystem in another directory that is not inspected by the scanner.

Comment: Solution 2) right? Create it in same target file system, and afterwards just move it since that will happen instant?

Comment: @Cristi That is right. `rename` syscall within the same filesystem creates a new filename and removes the old one atomically. The file content (aka inode) stays in the same place.